# Ability to see actual matched pscores and corresponding character data in R

Tags: r

I am doing propensity score matching for the indexed data using the `Matching` package. I have in total 3088 observations. Each line is attributed to the individual index number, and corresponding 18 factor values. Out of the data sample I have 125 observations which are treated. I am using GenMatch algorithm for this.  Please see my code below:

```
{    
x_2011 <- cbind(F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7,F8, F9, F10, F11, F12, F13, F14, F15, F16, F17, F18)
y_2011 <- cbind(np_2011)
tr_2011 <- cbind(treat_2011)
name <- cbind(index_name)

gen_2011 <- GenMatch(Tr = tr_2011, X = x_2011, BalanceMatrix = x_2011, pop.size = 300)
summary(gen_2011)

mgen_2011_2 <- Match(Y = y_2011, Tr = tr_2011,X = x_2011, Weight.matrix = gen_2011, estimand = "ATT")

MatchBalance(tr_2011 ~ x_2011, data = mydata_2011, match.out = mgen_2011_2, nboots = 0)

summary(mgen_2011_2)
}
```

where x_2011 is the cbind of the 18 factors. After running, I am able to see the output and the estimate.

Is it possible to see the index number and its corresponding pscore for the treated observations and the matched to it index number with the corresponding pscore?

Comment: Start by looking around at the contents of `str(mgen_2011_2)` and read the values section of `?Match`.

Comment: Yea, I was not able to find it over there on how to extract and match (assign) corresponding index names with the treated and controlled index

Comment: I would like to have the output that I can produce with Match function which is similar to after running Matchit function and be able to see index name, Y,X,Distance(Pscore) in the match.data(m.out). However, with the Matchit function I am not sure how to determine what is matched to what. But with the Match function, I believe first variables of the matched sample size of treated followed by the matched sample size equal to the controlled which are matched to the treated (in 1:1 matching).

Comment: If you know how to run MatchIt, use the genetic matching option in MatchIt (which calls Matching anyway). Reconstructing your original data set is hard after using Matching.